MVC pages are not running with ReactTS
We have a web application which runs on .NET 8 (recently we migrated from 5 to 8).
Now the team is planning to build new screens in ReactTS and merge these screens with the existing .NET 8 web application. So, it won't impact on the current customers. We also have a future plan to migrate the existing .NET web screens to React TS in phase wise manner
We are doing a POC with .NET Web App and ReactTS sample apps we tried different articles and approaches to run .NET application and ReactTS application on the Same domain and port number.
Example .NET 8 web app is running on https://localhost:44341 and trying to run ReactTS also on same port and they both reside in same solution. Our sample code uploaded in github
Can we run MVC pages and ReactTS pages from same project ?
We have configured our program.cs file like
 app.UseSpa(spa => 
{ 
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp"; 
        spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer("start"); 
});

When we run the application react pages are loading but MVC pages are not loading. We are using
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions package.
We are trying to run  .NET 8 and ReactTS so few screens will run on ReactTS and few screens will run on .NET 8 with same same domain and port

Are your looking for ReactJS.NET ? According to my knowledge, we can't add react project into mvc application directly.

Not looking for ReactJS.NET, We can add React to MVC project we got an article too. https://esausilva.com/2020/08/03/add-a-react-app-to-a-dot-net-core-mvc-app/

Hi Gopi, is it working for you? And seems we can't use  UseReactDevelopmentServer in .net8.

I am able to run application and react screens are working but MVC screens are not loading

bound to be a routing problem.  Really you should bite the bullet and let react create all views, while .NET serves only as a "webapi" that returns JSON.  (Those endpoints will be routed to a different folder... i.e: your_domain.com/webapi/your_endpoint_that_returns_JSON, while react is served from your_domain.com  There should be a basic template for this in Visual Studio... something like ".NET + React"

@browsermator As stated in the description we wanted to run both WebApp(not API) and React both. we have already API we running it on different port

You won't need a different port.  Just use different folders... something like /webapi/ for endpoints that return JSON, and /mvc/ for standard pages.  (It'll depend on whether you want react's index returned from main URL, or ASP.NET's MVC index returned from main URL.)  Any link to an MVC page should be a standard link and not processed through react.
